# The member `System.Collections.Generic.List<BasePlayer>.Count' cannot be used as method or delegate

Tags: c#

Here is some of my Code for a plugin on a game, if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace Oxide.Plugins
{
    [Info("Fake Player Add Plugin", "NOT asmr", 0.0)]
    class FakePlayerAddPlugin : CSharpPlugin
    {
        public int MaximumFakePlayer = 50; //if server has more than x legit players, dont add fakes.
        public int PlayerFakeAdd = 43; //how many fake players to add
        public float PlayerCheckDelay = 120f; //how often to check for player changes in seconds

        void Loaded()
        {
            Puts("FakePlayerAddPlugin Loaded!");
        }

        float lasttime = 0f;

        void OnFrame(float delta)
        {
            if (lasttime + PlayerCheckDelay > Time.realtimeSinceStartup) return;

            lasttime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

            var pcount = BasePlayer.activePlayerList?.Count(n => n.IsValid()) ?? 0;
            var fcount = BasePlayer.activePlayerList?.Count(n => n == null) ?? 0;

            if (pcount >= MaximumFakePlayer)
            {
                RemoveFakePlayers();
                return;
            }

            if (PlayerFakeAdd > 0 && fcount != PlayerFakeAdd)
            {
                RemoveFakePlayers();
                AddFakePlayers(PlayerFakeAdd);
            }
        }

        public void RemoveFakePlayers()
        {
            BasePlayer.activePlayerList.RemoveAll(n => n == null);
        }

        public void AddFakePlayers(int amount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                BasePlayer.activePlayerList.Add(null);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

"The member `System.Collections.Generic.List.Count' cannot be used as method or delegate" is what I am getting back.

Comment: Have you tried doing a .Where from System.Linq then .Count?

Comment: @JamieTwells There's a LinQ Count that supports it, I'm pretty sure the OP is missing `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure if filtering inside the Count was supported. I don't like doing it so I never use them, I always filter with where, then call methods like Any, First, and Count. It seems more consistent to me.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I sure was, thank you!